# AngularJS + Webpack Mysterious Bug - Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, typeerror

I'm working on a project using AngularJS with Webpack, I'm getting a very weird bug:

Sometimes an error will show up:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (vendor.js:51)
    at Object.357 (templates.js:377)
    at __webpack_require__ (vendor.js:51)
    at exam (app.js:17755)
    at Object.invoke (vendor.js:21978)
    at vendor.js:24895
    at forEach (vendor.js:17592)
    at Object.<anonymous> (vendor.js:24893)
    at Object.invoke (vendor.js:21978)
    at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (vendor.js:21817)(anonymous function) @ vendor.js:30912
```

The weird part: When i comment out the recently changed piece of code, and re-insert it (such that the code is the same), it suddenly works for a little while, then the same error appears !

I don't have the slightest clue as to what's causing this, Any help will be greatly appreciated.